# Object not showing up in Blender 2.8 render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I've created a scene and every part of it is visible as intended in the realtime render view.

[image: Realtime render]

However, when I do my final render the hill object is invisible and only the grass particle system shows through.

[image: Final render]

I really don't know what is causing this so any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure "show emitter" is checked in the render section of your particle settings
 [image: Shown here]

Comment: Thank you! :) That was the issue.